# read the office add-in manifest file from the react app which is inside the Outlook task pane

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I'm looking for a way to read resource strings and URLs from the add-in manifest.

Does someone know a way?

Thanks!

Comment: Currently there is no JS API available to read manifest information from add-in code. Can you please explain us the use-case for this?

Comment: I want to add different behaviors to the application, according to "environment variables", and I thought to store those variables in the manifest file.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Where should endpoints for ajax calls be stored in office addins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the manifest file is hosted anywhere and the URL is clearly defined on the web server you can use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) Web API to get the data programmatically. Otherwise, there is no way - `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: Great idea, I'll try it.
Thanks!